# gCan't use Styles anymore

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**Edit 2:** Here is a [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwOPtyRizrOoWFpSV0xDMmR1MFk/view?usp=sharing) to the project.

**Edit:** Not sure what has happened to my Project, but it seems to have messed up big time. Getting multiple errors saying a load of my converters don't exist in the namespace, when they do!

Here I have got an instance of a Class defined in XAML:

```
<Application x:Class="Test_Project.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test_Project">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:runtimeObject x:Key="runtimeVariables" />
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/Generic.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

But it does exist here, as you can see below! This has just randomly suddenly messed up!

```
namespace Test_Project
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);

            //Startup
            Window main = new MainWindow();
            main.Show();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Global values for use during application runtime
    /// </summary>
    public class runtimeObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    ....
```

---

Not too sure what has gone wrong here, for some reason now I can't use a new ResourceDirectory I have made. Getting this error now:

> The type or namespace name 'Styles' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Test_Project' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

The error is on the following line:
**NotificationWindow.g.cs**

```
using Test_Project.Styles;
```

**NotificationWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Test_Project.Views.NotificationWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test_Project.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Notification" Style="{StaticResource NotificationWindow}">
    <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0,1" >
        <!-- Notification area -->
        <Border>
            <StackPanel Margin="20">
                <TextBlock>
                    Hello
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>

        <!-- Animation -->
        <Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0"/>
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="1"/>
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="0"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>

        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1" />
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is my **App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="Test_Project.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test_Project">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:runtimeObject x:Key="runtimeVariables" />
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/Generic.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**Generic.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test_Project.Styles">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Buttons.xaml" /> <!-- All Button Styles -->
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Misc.xaml" /> <!-- All Misc Styles -->
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Notifications.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Here you can see my Project File Structure:

[image]

Comment: Not sure it is same thing but I had some bad XAML that did that.  It was not bad enough Visual Studio showed an error but I had a single bad character outside a />.

Comment: Hmm, I have had a look and I can't seem to find anything :/ It's also happening on multiple files, mainly everything which referees to the namespace :S For example: `<Converters:StartPointConverter x:Key="StartPointConverter" />` has the same error

Comment: Dont worry about the converter erros, they go away when you fix the namespace problem, can you provide some more code or even the project?

Comment: Is there a `XAML` Window/UserControl named `Notification` if so please post the XAML for that window/UserControl.

Comment: Yes I was getting problems on multiple files.  You have done clean and rebuild?

Comment: @BrunoJoaquim I have added a download link

Comment: @AbinMathew, there was, I deleted that Window and made another one, same issue. I have updated the post and provided NotificationWindow.xaml content

Comment: do you have a style named `NotificationWindow` ( 'Style="{StaticResource NotificationWindow}') try removing that and debug.

Comment: where is that defined as static resource ?

Comment: `Styles > Notifications.xaml`and then `Styles > Generic.xaml` merges the dictionaries.

Comment: Remove 'Style="{StaticResource NotificationWindow}' from your NotificationWindow and try. if the same error exists ?

Comment: Done that, didn't solve the issue. All my linked things have seemed to have broken and I can't figure out why! https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=BAAC565D114ED976!2743&authkey=!ALOzmDcYTvMGIgk&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

Comment: There is a link to the project in my original post if you would take a look ?

Comment: the project u have uploaded missing a dll/project named `Controls`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94986/discussion-between-abin-mathew-and-martyn-ball).

Comment: did you change some xaml file folder?

Comment: @BrunoJoaquim All I have done is create a new folder called `Views` and moved `MainWindow.xaml` into that folder, and made a new Window called `NotificationWindow.xaml` in that folder :S

Comment: @BrunoJoaquim, does it allow you join the chat? 
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94986/discussion-between-abin-mathew-and-martyn-ball

Comment: Did you try to delete everything in ShadowCache? I've used to have problems with styles because of this. Clearing it resolved issues for me. You might give it a try. Path: AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Designer\ShadowCache - delete the content.

Comment: @MichalKozak, just tried this, didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I went onto the Microsoft forums and someone helped me find the issue. When I created a ResourceDictionary it generated a local tag which has the namespace of `clr-namespace:namespacehere.Styles`.

This was seemed to make my new window generate a file called Window1.g.cs within it had the line `using namespacehere.Styles;` which was causing the problem.

```
#pragma checksum "..\..\..\Views\NotificationWindow.xaml" "{406ea660-64cf-4c82-b6f0-42d48172a799}" "922E7A4BDAE53DAC4A05221020498CA6"
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using PhotoManagement.Converters;
using PhotoManagement.Styles; //Error occurs here!
using PhotoManagement.Views;
using System;
```

So I had to search the entire solution and remove any reference of `namespacehere.Styles` which seemed to cause the issue, as it is seen here:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PhotoManagement"
                    xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:PhotoManagement.Converters">
```

Before is had `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PhotoManagement.Styles"`.